# How to know what SDKs a user will require for my .Net app

Tags: .net, installation, sdk

I am building a Windows desktop app using .Net 8.0 and I want to know what requirements/dependencies my user would already need installed on their system in order to run my app. For example, if they didn't already have it would they need to download the 8.0 SDK? Or is that somehow packaged with my app when creating an installer via Visual Studio?

In general, how does an app developer determine software (not hardware) requirements for the user's system? Such as OS version, SDKs, etc.

I am very new to creating apps from the ground up, so sorry if this is obvious. Thanks!

Comment: it depends on how you publish! you might want "self contained": https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained (but look at all the options on that page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SDK" stands for "Software Development Kit". You rarely need a SDK if you only want to run the software.

For .Net it will depend on the type of deployment you use.

- With "[self contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained)" publishing you package all needed files with your installation, so nothing extra need to be installed. But your package will be significantly bigger than a framework dependent install.
- With "framework dependent" publishing the client needs a [*.Net runtime*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net80). There are different runtimes for desktop, console and web applications. It is possible to include the runtime as part of an installer.

For a typical .Net windows desktop application you can just make a self contained package and not need to worry about anything else. Also consider [single file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli).

> In general, how does an app developer determine software (not hardware) requirements for the user's system? Such as OS version, SDKs, etc.

You look up compatibility lists, like [this one for .Net framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies), or [this one for .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net80). If you use any third party software that need installing you need to look at the documentation for that software so see what and how it should be installed.

You usually want to make the user experience as simple as possible, and that might include creating an installer that installs any required dependencies. In other cases you need to create an installation guide that details the specific steps needed to install the software. For some complex enterprise software you need a trained technicians to install it.

You also need to test your software in various environments, often using virtual machines. This should find potential compatibility problems and allow you to address them.